# How to push the object properties from one array object to other array object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

```
var result = [
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "4545", Country: "US", Province: "TX" },
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "5655455", Country: "US", Province: "TX" },
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "123", Country: "US", Province: "TX" },
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "456", Country: "US", Province: "TX" }]

var validation = [
    { valid: "enter correct code" },
    { valid: "control does  not exist" },
    { valid: "control does  not exist" },
    { valid: "control does  not exist" }]
```

I want this-

```
result= [
    {Type: "Regular", valid: "enter correct code",Code: "abc", Control: "4545", Country: "US", Province:"TX"},
    {Type: "Regular", valid: "control does  not exist", Code: "abc", Control: "5655455", Country: "US", Province:"TX"},
    {Type: "Regular", valid: "control does  not exist", Code: "abc", Control: "123", Country: "US", Province:"TX"},
    {Type: "Regular", valid: "control does  not exist", Code: "abc", Control: "456", Country: "US", Province:"TX"}]
```

There are 2 array of objects. I want to push the object attributes of validation object to the result array object at the given index. How can i do that in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate through `result` and set `result[index]["valid"] = validation[index]["valid"];`

```js
var result = [
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "4545", Country: "US", Province: "TX" },
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "5655455", Country: "US", Province: "TX" },
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "123", Country: "US", Province: "TX" },
    { Type: "Regular", Code: "abc", Control: "456", Country: "US", Province: "TX" }]

var validation = [
    { valid: "enter correct code" },
    { valid: "control does  not exist" },
    { valid: "control does  not exist" },
    { valid: "control does  not exist" }]

for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
    const element = result[index];
    element["valid"] = validation[index]["valid"];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks , i want the 'valid' to be at index 1 , the result is showing the 'valid' at the last position. how can i do that?

Comment: @harleenkaur You have to create a new Json array then, and you have to add key: value  pair in correct order you want to in each item in that array